# Wordpress insert data into a custom table

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form data that i would like to put into a basic table for reporting purposes. I can create views and have the view data inserted into a table via cron job. But this is causing issues with back up and restore as well as other issues with my host. I cant quite get a table to table php function to work. I would like to have this function run and insert the data into a table. Here is what i have,

```
   add_action( 'runmfin', 'runfin' );
function runfin() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('TRUNCATE TABLE Master_Findings');
    $sql = 'insert into `Master_Findings` (select `AZ`.`Builder` AS `Service Number`,`AZ`.`Community` AS `Community`,`AZ`.`Lot` AS `Lot`,`AZ`.`Address` AS `Address`,`AZ`.`City` AS `City`,`AZ`.`State` AS `State`,`AZ`.`Zip` AS `Zip`,`AZ`.`Requested_QA_Date` AS `Requested_QA_Date`,`AZ`.`Inspection_Type` AS `Inspection_Type`,`AZ`.`Area` AS `Area`,`AZ`.`Component` AS `Component`,`AZ`.`Item Description` AS `Item Description`,`AZ`.`Trade` AS `Trade`,`AZ`.`Notes` AS `Notes`,`AZ`.`ID` AS `ID`,`AZ`.`Status` AS `Status` from (select `A`.`meta_value` AS `Builder`,`B`.`meta_value` AS `Community`,`c`.`meta_value` AS `Lot`,`d`.`meta_value` AS `Address`,`e`.`meta_value` AS `City`,`f`.`meta_value` AS `State`,`g`.`meta_value` AS `Zip`,`h`.`meta_value` AS `Requested_QA_Date`,`i`.`meta_value` AS `Inspection_Type`,`j`.`meta_value` AS `Area`,`k`.`meta_value` AS `Component`,`l`.`meta_value` AS `Item Description`,`m`.`meta_value` AS `Trade`,`n`.`meta_value` AS `Notes`,`o`.`meta_value` AS `ID`,`p`.`meta_value` AS `Status` from (((((((((((((((((select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 12)))) `A` left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 20))) `B` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `B`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 14))) `c` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `c`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 13.1))) `d` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `d`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 13.3))) `e` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `e`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 13.4))) `f` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `f`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 13.5))) `g` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `g`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 25))) `h` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `h`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 24))) `i` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `i`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 7))) `j` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `j`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 8))) `k` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `k`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 17))) `l` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `l`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 22))) `m` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `m`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 10))) `o` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `o`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 21))) `p` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `p`.`entry_id`))) left join (select `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`entry_id` AS `entry_id`,`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` from `wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta` where ((`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`form_id` = 24) and (`wp_biltriteinspec`.`wp_gf_entry_meta`.`meta_key` = 18))) `n` on((`A`.`entry_id` = `n`.`entry_id`))))) `AZ`';
    $wpdb->query( $sql );

}
```

Comment: What kind of filter/hook is `runmfin` supposed to be?

Comment: Its used to trigger that function via cron job. I have a cron running everyday that should be triggering that qry.

Comment: Should, or _did_? Verify that first of all. Also, `$wpdb->query` has a return value, that tells you whether it succeeded or not; and further methods to get an error message when it didn’t.

Comment: Sorry it does run. I am also using a manual run method and it does run. The qry just isnt working for the insert.

Comment: Well then go and figure out why. Have you tried to test this query using a database frontend like phpMyAdmin yet?

Comment: i can test the SQL part and that works fine. I wasnt sure i could test the whole php function in phpadmin

Comment: No, of course you can’t. If the query on its own works, but not when you try to execute it using $wpdb->query - then use the methods that class provides, to figure out what actually went wrong.

Comment: ok thank you, i appreciate your insight and help. I will take a deeper dive.

Answer (score 0):

So although the same qry ran fine in a view , i needed to create a another alias for 1 of the sun qrys